# BufferedImage to JavaFX image

Tags: java, javafx

I have an image I screenshot from the primary monitor and I want to add it to a Java FX `ImageView` as so:

```
@FXML
protected ImageView screenshot() throws AWTException, IOException {
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    Image image = capture; //Error
    imageView.setImage(image);
    return imageView;
}
```

I'm trying to set the `BufferedImage capture` to `javafx.scene.image.Image image` but the types are incompatible nor am I able to cast it. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use

```
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(capture, null);
```

Comment: Can you comment about the performance of this solution? Is there a way to directly create `javafx.scene.image.Image` without first creating `BufferedImage`?

Comment: I had the exact same question when I got here. I looked in the implementation of SwingFXUtils and saw it's indeed possible if you create a JavaFX WritableImage. In that case you can get its PixelWriter and just write a data buffer to the image. This is very fast and similar to what you'd do with a BufferedImage. I got very good performance out of this.

Answer (score 9):

normally the best choice is `Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(capture, null);` in java9 or bigger.... but in matter of performance in javafx, also in devices with low performance, you can use this technique that will do the magic, tested in java8

```
private static Image convertToFxImage(BufferedImage image) {
    WritableImage wr = null;
    if (image != null) {
        wr = new WritableImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        PixelWriter pw = wr.getPixelWriter();
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                pw.setArgb(x, y, image.getRGB(x, y));
            }
        }
    }

    return new ImageView(wr).getImage();
}
```

Comment: What kind of magic is that? For me this looks like the slowest possible solution to copy over any single pixel individually.

Comment: looks like that but beleive me, it works fast, I test it in Raspian devices (slow performance also in a slow internet) and in both windos a linux (ubuntu), the behavior was the same (always using javafx from jre1.8). I needed to find another solution and this is what I found. use the soltion that best suits you

Comment: You can skip the creation of the BufferedImage if you just want to convert a byte[] to a JavaFX image - see the comment of the user "FinalArt2005" under the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

converting a **1080x2280** (TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) java.awt.image.BufferedImage into a javafx.scene.image.Image turned out to be harder than expected.

**the solution of Reimeus ran in 15ms**

**the solution of Dan ran in 210ms**

**my solution runs in 6ms**

```
private Image getImage(BufferedImage img){
    //converting to a good type, read about types here: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/PixelBuffer.html
    BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
    newImg.createGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);

    //converting the BufferedImage to an IntBuffer
    int[] type_int_agrb = ((DataBufferInt) newImg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.wrap(type_int_agrb);

    //converting the IntBuffer to an Image, read more about it here: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/PixelBuffer.html
    PixelFormat<IntBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getIntArgbPreInstance();
    PixelBuffer<IntBuffer> pixelBuffer = new PixelBuffer(newImg.getWidth(), newImg.getHeight(), buffer, pixelFormat);
    return new WritableImage(pixelBuffer);
}
```