# How to retrieve thumbnail picture of an mp3 file using java

Tags: java, mp3, thumbnails

I have problem getting mp3 file thumbnail using java, for example we have file:

```
File MP3File = new File(<directory>);
```

So, How can i retrieve its thumbnail?

Thanks for your attention, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
Image icn=((ImageIcon) FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(<directory>))).getImage();
icn = icn.getScaledInstance(32,32, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Comment: Thanks , that works but how can i covert java.awt.image to java.scene.image.image in order to show it in an image view?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure since I can't test this on my system but you can look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970005/bufferedimage-to-javafx-image

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the metadata from the mp3 file, see  [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) from github.

According from the tutorial, I think you could get a byte[] and convert into a bufferedImage.