# JavaFX get Icon from exe file

Tags: java, javafx

When using swing I am able to use `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file)` to get a awt `Icon` object from an exe file.  I now need to use JavaFX, but am lost as to how to get an image I can display in an `ImageView`.  Is there a way to convert the image or perhaps a similar method as `getSystemIcon`, but for javafx?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970005/bufferedimage-to-javafx-image

Comment: that requires a BufferImage, but we have an Icon here

Comment: Yes one would need an ugly conversion using `paintIcon` AFAIK. A newer link with moved package: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html It might be more maintainable, that when the .exe stems from something like InnoSetup to generate the icon file too.

Comment: it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145329/fetch-icons-of-my-system